# SQLiteException no such column user_email

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I'm finding similar questions that all involve missing commas, whitespaces, etc. However, I'm not finding anything like that in my code, so those answers are not helping me here, unless I've completely missed something in my syntax.

I am trying to figure out why I am getting the error

```
SQLiteException no such column: user_email (code 1):, while compiling: 
SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_email=?
```

when I click my Register button. Here is onClick and postDataToSQLite methods from my Register Activity class:

```
 /**
 * This implemented method is to listen the click on view
 *
 * @param v
 */
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.appCompatButtonRegister:
            postDataToSQLite();
            break;

        case R.id.appCompatTextViewLoginLink:
            finish();
            break;
    }
}
/**
 * This method is to validate the input text fields and post data to SQLite
 */
private void postDataToSQLite() {
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextName, textInputLayoutName, getString(R.string.error_message_name))) {
        return;
    }
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextEmail, textInputLayoutEmail, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
        return;
    }
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextEmail(textInputEditTextEmail, textInputLayoutEmail, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
        return;
    }
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextPassword, textInputLayoutPassword, getString(R.string.error_message_password))) {
        return;
    }
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextMatches(textInputEditTextPassword, textInputEditTextConfirmPassword,
            textInputLayoutConfirmPassword, getString(R.string.error_password_match))) {
        return;
    }

    if (!databaseHelper.checkUser(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim())) {

        user.setName(textInputEditTextName.getText().toString().trim());
        user.setEmail(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim());
        user.setPassword(textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim());

        databaseHelper.addUser(user);

        // Snack Bar to show success message that record saved successfully
        Snackbar.make(nestedScrollView, getString(R.string.success_message), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        emptyInputEditText();
    } else {
        // Snack Bar to show error message that record already exists
        Snackbar.make(nestedScrollView, getString(R.string.error_email_exists), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Here is my DatabaseHelper class:

```
package sql;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.database.Cursor;
import modal.User;



/**
 * Created by christopher on 9/21/17.
 */

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

//Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "WillowHQ.db";

//User table name
private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

//User Table Column names
private static final String COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";
private static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "user_name";
private static final String COLUMN_USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
private static final String COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";

//create table sql query
private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "(" + COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";

//drop table sql query
private String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param context
 */
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    //Drop User Table if exists
    db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);

    //create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
/**
 * Create user record
 *
 * @param user
 */
public void addUser(User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME, user.getName());
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());

    //Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
    db.close();
}
/**
 * Fetch all users and return the list of user records
 *
 * @return list
 */
public List<User> getAllUser() {
    //array of columns to fetch
    String[] columns = {
            COLUMN_USER_ID,
            COLUMN_USER_EMAIL,
            COLUMN_USER_NAME,
            COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD
    };
    //sorting orders
    String sortOrder =
            COLUMN_USER_NAME + " ASC";
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    //query the user table
    /**
     * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
     * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
     * SELECT user_id,user_name,user_email,user_password FROM user ORDER BY user_name;
     */
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, columns, null, null, null, null, sortOrder);

    //Traversing through all rows and adding to the list
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_ID))));
            user.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_NAME)));
            user.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL)));
            user.setPassword(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD)));
            // Adding user record to list
            userList.add(user);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // return user list
    return userList;
}
/**
 * This method to update user record
 *
 * @param user
 */
public void updateUser(User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME, user.getName());
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());

    // updating row
    db.update(TABLE_USER, values, COLUMN_USER_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(user.getId())});
    db.close();
}

/**
 * This method is to delete user record
 *
 * @param user
 */
public void deleteUser(User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // delete user record by id
    db.delete(TABLE_USER, COLUMN_USER_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(user.getId())});
    db.close();
}

/**
 * This method to check user exist or not
 *
 * @param email
 * @return true/false
 */
public boolean checkUser(String email) {

    // array of columns to fetch
    String[] columns = {
            COLUMN_USER_ID
    };
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // selection criteria
    String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?";

    // selection argument
    String[] selectionArgs = {email};

    // query user table with condition
    /**
     * function is used to fetch records from user table 
     * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
     * SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_email = 'my_name@email.com';
     */

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, //Table to query
                columns,                    //columns to return
                selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
                selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                       //group the rows
                null,                      //filter by row groups
                null);                      //The sort order
        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

    if (cursorCount > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
/**
 * This method to check user exist or not
 *
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * @return true/false
 */
public boolean checkUser(String email, String password) {

    // array of columns to fetch
    String[] columns = {
            COLUMN_USER_ID
    };
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    // selection criteria
    String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?" + " AND " + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " = ?";

    // selection arguments
    String[] selectionArgs = {email, password};

    // query user table with conditions
    /**
     * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
     * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
     * SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_email = 'myname@email.com.com' AND user_password = 'whatever';
     */
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

    int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    if (cursorCount > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible this table was created before the user_email column was appended to the create table query?

Answer (score 0):

I learned something today. I did indeed have a syntax error in my CREATE_USER_TABLE string. I looked in my Local History in Android Studio, and discovered that it was originally:

```
private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "(" + COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_USER_NAME + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";
```

And the new version is:

```
private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "(" + COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";
```

**However**, the problem was that after fixing that problem, I did not remove the app from my emulator, which was causing the error. All I had to do was delete the app, and let the onCreate() method do its thing. Problem solved. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can export this table,and check it.if not root,you can copy it to another Folder (operable).suggestion:

- sqlite code printf to screen
- Use a simple tool to verify its correctness，like "sqliteMan"
- It is best to first confirm the correctness of the sql on the tool, and then write the code (for their own do not confirm the code)

Personal opinion, do not like to spray.
i

Answer (score 0):

There are some cases where you already created table columns and you modified it but it doesn't modify. You can clear cache or clear data the application. Hope this works.